# Odoo search multiple names uses OR operator

Tags: javascript, python, search, odoo, odoo-8

Whenever I use search on a particular name, press enter, followed by a new name. Odoo automatically interprets this as a OR operator. When I actually want is a AND operator.

[image]

Any ideas how I can adjust this in de code (JavaScript or Python?)

Thanks

Comment: You can use advance search option, and search the names multiple times, one by one, in this case it will apply 'AND' condition to it.

Comment: yes I know, but much less efficient

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

See module below, this will change the default OR behavior to AND when pressing the SHIFT key

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_search_with_and/

Comment: This was great. It wasn't available for Odoo 14 so I just looked at the source for the addon version for Odoo 13 and it's just a few lines of code to change the default operator to AND. Thank you @Jesse